# JMeter WebDriver Sampler doesn't work and doesnt have headless

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am using jp@gc - Firefox Driver Config plugin to hit some URL and assert some element in UI.
But I am not able to launch firefox driver as I cant see an option to enable to run firefox as a headless browser .

**JP@GC - WebDriver Sampler:**

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait

def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser,5000);

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart(); WDS.browser.get('https://google.com/'); wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//input[@name='q']"))); WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()

Answer (score 1):

How about checking `Headless` box in the jp@gc - [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/)?

[image]

---

Going forward be aware that you can always bypass any JMeter limitation by implementing whatever you want/need using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223), example code to kick off a headless Firefox would be something like:

```
System.setProperty('webdriver.gecko.driver','c:/apps/webdriver/geckodriver.exe')
def options = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions()
options.addArguments('--headless')
def driver = new org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver(options)
driver.get('http://example.com')
log.info('Current page title: ' + driver.getTitle())
driver.quit()
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: I have used JSR223 sampler and used above code , it's working fine, thanks for help